# what does asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1)) mean

Tags: python-asyncio

Does code below mean anything? If it does, what's the scenario to use it? What's difference if the sleep time is different?

```
...
while True:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))
...
```

Comment: It basically means that you're sleeping for a second, there's no much point on using that because it does the same thing as `time.sleep(1)`.

Comment: `run_until_complete()` runs not only the given task, but also any other runnable tasks, until the given task completes. The above loop could have a meaning if some tasks were scheduled using `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(xxx)` prior to the loop's execution. In that case the `while` loop as shown might be designed not to run `sleep()` (which would indeed be useless), but to give the event loop a time slot of 1s to run, and then (presumably in the loop) do some non-asyncio checks.

Comment: Thanks, @user4815162342, could you give an example, please?

Comment: @BobLee I'm not sure what kind of example you're looking for - I was making an educated guess based on the (incomplete) code you provided. If anything, you should update the question to include more context, otherwise it's impossible to answer and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from one comment which I think answered my question:

> run_until_complete() runs not only the given task, but also any other runnable tasks, until the given task completes. The above loop could have a meaning if some tasks were scheduled using asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(xxx) prior to the loop's execution. In that case the while loop as shown might be designed not to run sleep() (which would indeed be useless), but to give the event loop a time slot of 1s to run, and then (presumably in the loop) do some non-asyncio checks.